# Stereo Matching Baseline Evaluation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

The **stereo matching problem** consists of obtaining a correspondence between right and left images. I want to do an evaluation between a baseline and a **Dynamic Programming** method. However, I don't have a baseline yet. I would like to know which method should I use. I was thinking to try a brute-force algorithm. Is there something like that in the literature?

What do you suggest as a baseline method? I want a simple solution, something without heuristics and optimizations, such as this brute-force strategy . But, I have no material to research about it, only methods using Graph Cut, Dynamic Programming *etc.*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Middlebury Univ. reference datasets and database of algorithms are the standard everyone uses for evaluation these days.

http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/

Comment: They disponibilize codes which would be very useful for me in order to do an evaluation. Have you ever used those codes? I've tried to compile them on a Ubuntu 11.10, but every source has gcc bugs that I have to fix one-by-one.

Comment: Problem solved. There are templated methods declared in `MinFilter.h` and implemented in `MinFilter.cpp`. When using templates, the implementation must be located in the header file. So, I just had to copy the implementation to the header file. `$ mv MinFilter.cpp MinFilter.h`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the basics before delving into graph cuts. Consult the relevant chapter here, it might help http://szeliski.org/Book/